# How to use layout-wrap?

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

How to do list items by angular-material layout-wrap? 
I want to do like this

```
1 4 6
2 5 7
3 6 8
```

Not

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GCWQx3?p=preview

Or is it impossible?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with angular, but try switching `layout="row"` to `layout="column"`. You may also need to specify a height for content to know where to wrap.

Comment: yes. "playing" with height helped  http://plnkr.co/edit/PaEEGw?p=preview

Comment: http://codepen.io/01/pen/BNbpLN

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to convert the blue area into a flexbox then:

```
.mainHeight {
   display:flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
    min-height:calc(100% - 86px);
    height: calc(100% - 86px);
}
```

[**FORK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eK8iIE?p=preview)

**Note**: I changed the spelling from `.mainHeigth` to `.mainHeight` in CSS and HTML